# Удаление элемента списка при for (auto& i : list)

Tags: c++, std-list

Есть цикл:

```
for ( auto& whizbang : m_whizbangs )
{
    if ( IsClush((*whizbang), (*whizbang).GetDirection(), time) )
    {
        (*whizbang).Hit();
        m_whizbangs.remove(whizbang);

    }
    else
    {
        (*whizbang).Move(time);
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку, что итератор не увеличиваемый. У меня была такая ошибка, когда я работал с таким синтаксисом:

```
for (std::list<unique_ptr<Whizbang>>::iterator i = m_whizbangs.begin(); i < m_whizbangs.end())
```

И я её исправил, тогда я удалял так:

```
if (...)
    i = m_whizbangs.erase(i);
else
    ++i;
```

Как нужно удалять при таком синтаксисе? И можно ли как-нибудь использовать erase, а не remove, так как remove по сути ничего не удаляет, а просто заполняет конец списка мусором.

Comment: А вы не думали использовать std::remove_if? Я думаю стаким циклом удалять не получится и надо использовать итераторы.

Comment: @Unick Думаю remove_if не решит этой рпоблемы

Comment: с ним вам не надо самим писать цикл, и следовательно проблема может не возникунуть.

Comment: @Unick Но без цикла я не узнаю какой элемент удалять.

Comment: В remove_if вы передаёте функцию, которая решает какой элемент удалять. Параметром функции этот элемент передаётся. Вам же не нужен индекс элемента для удаления?

Comment: @Сергей, Unick прав, как раз, таки, решит )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Диапазонная версия цикла `for` обеспечивает доступ к элементу, а не к итератору, т.е. нормальное удаление элементов в таком цикле не является возможным (можно модифицировать элемент в контейнере, но нельзя модифицировать сам контейнер). Чтобы это понимать достаточно взглянуть на то, во что по Стандарту [разворачивается](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1) `range-based-for`.

> The range-based for statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
>     auto __begin = begin-expr ;
>     auto __end = end-expr ;
>     for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
m_whizbangs.erase( std::remove_if( m_whizbangs.begin(), m_whizbangs.end(), []
(Whizbang * el) -> bool 
{
   // condition
}), m_whizbangs.end());
```

А так Вам не подойдет ?

Comment: Используя лямбду, обходите Ваш вектор, выбираете подходящие для удаления элементы. Условие прошу писать на место _// condition_

Comment: Если изменять цикл, то мне просто проще будет написать с итераторами. Я хотел узнать именно про первый вариант. Спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 0):

а свой цикл и не нужен чтобы знать какой элемент удалять, цикл уже есть в remove_if, нужен только класс-функтор или функция в которую будет передаваться элемент массива и возвращающая true/false, удалять/"не удалять"

```
ForwardIt remove_if( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

p   -   унарный предикат, который возвращает​true , если элемент должен быть удален. 
Определение функции предиката должны быть эквивалентно следующему:

```
bool pred(const Type &a);
```

Определение не должно иметь **const &**, но функция не должна модифицировать принимаемые объекты.
Тип Type должен быть таков, что объект типа ForwardIt может быть разыменован и затем неявно преобразован в Type. ​