# Как взять i элемент в set

Tags: c++, set

Есть такой фрагмент когда, где s1, s2 это:

```
set<string> s1;
set<string> s2;
```

```
for (int j=0;j<s1.size();++j)
{
    if (s2.count(s1[j]))
    {
        ++n;
    }
}
```

Мне надо как-то обратиться к `j` элементу, но компилятор ругается и выдает следующую ошибку:

> ```
> error: no match for ‘operator[]’ 
> (operand types are ‘std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘int’)
> if (s2.count(s1[j]))
> ```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как обратиться к `j` элементу через обычный цикл `for`.

Answer (score 1):

`set` - это множество. Обращаться надо по ключу, который в данном случае - строка, а не целое. Поэтому никаких индексов (целочисленных) быть не должно. Для перебора значений можно использовать range-for. А может быть и вовсе воспользоваться каким-нибудь `std::` алгоритмом.

Используя range-for цикл можно изменить ваш код таким образом:

```
for (const auto& e1: s1) {
    if (s2.count(e1)) {
        ++n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне надо реализовать без range-for, через обычный цикл for. Но почему-то к тому же vector или string можно обращаться через индекс

Comment: @Fedor зачем обычный for? Потому что так препод сказал? set не заточен на обращение по индексам.

Comment: @Fedor _к тому же vector или string можно обращаться через индекс_ - потому что у них определен соответствующий оператор, а для `set` - не определен.

Comment: Да, именно так, но разве range-for сам по индексам не идет? А как тогда пройтись по s2, не используя индексы

Comment: @Fedor [range-for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557118/176217) работает с итераторами, а не с индексами. Пройтись по `s2` можно точно так же как и по `s1`, аналогичным циклом.

Comment: Ну перекопируйте `set` в `vector` и идите по индексам, если вы такой непонятливый...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, обычный for - это вовсе не обязательно по индлексу.

Comment: @Harry и тебе ^^

Comment: В вопросе проблема указана не как `++n, если count()`, а очень четко: *Мне надо как-то обратиться к j элементу*. Поэтому и предложен вариант `for(int i =  0; i < Vector.size(); ++i)...` — как такой `for` может работать *не по индексу*?

Answer (score 0):

> Мне надо реализовать без range-for, через обычный цикл for.

```
for (auto it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end(); ++it)
  n += s2.count(e1);
```